# Using jQuery Plugins with $.on()

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 2.1.1.

I have a page that dynamically loads content with the jQuery `$.ajax` and I'm using this plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/).

I cannot find the right syntax to get corner to work with on(). I have tried:

```
$("#CornerDiv").on("load", corner());
$("#CornerDiv").on("load", $("#CornerDiv").corner());
$("#CornerDiv").on("load", $(this).corner());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply the `.corner()` plugin after you output the AJAX response (in success).

Comment: You could also do `$("#CornerDiv").on("load", corner);`